# pytest : testing two packages with same root name

Tags: python, pytest, conda, modulenotfounderror

I have the following case:
I have a package Y which have module xxx.yyy
I have another package Z which have module xxx.zzz and he use several classes from xxx.yyy.
I want to have for both packages same entry module name xxx.
Now, when I install in conda env the first package Y and trying to run a pytest for the second package Z in a development folder, I got a error that "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named xxx.yyy"
If I run pytest with  --import-mode append, I got that xxx.zzz module is not found.
If I rename the xxx module in Z package with xxx1, the pytest found all modules.
If I run ipython I can see the installed Y package.
The output of the sys.path clearly shows that the Y package is in the correct path for the given conda env.
If I install the Z package in the same conda env, the classes from X package are visible in the Z package.

Definitely the problem is in the pytest. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: do you have __init__.py file under Y and Z packages ? add this file if not.